# How to find build.sbt with Scala code?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to find build.sbt with Scala. 
I can find build.sbt with java.io.File like this:

```
scala.io.Source.fromFile("build.sbt")
```

But I don't think this is the best practice. I thought about Typesafe Config, but it deals not with build file but with environment file.

Could you tell me more efficient way to find build.sbt with Scala.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `build.sbt` file once you've found it?

Comment: What do you want to do with it? `build.sbt` is not a regular Scala file, so might have a problem parsing it.

Comment: I meant I want to replace string in build.sbt only in sbt project.